# What causes that characteristic chirping noise in switching power supplies?

Tags: power-supply

Every now and then a switching power supply like the ones from mobile phones, laptops, etc. makes this very characteristic chirping noise.

What component in there causes that noise, and why?

Comment: At no load? Probably skip mode and coil whine.

Comment: Are talking about the power supply inside the device?

Answer (score 3):

That is most likely transformer coil whine. The windings vibrate along with the changes in the magnetic field.

Comment: This is called magnetostriction. Windings have not been sealed with epoxy resin to stop this. Cheap products.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Justme Coil whine is the likely culprit but to expand on that the chirping is the frequency of the input power as the AC "turns over" it creates a sine wave-based sound and the equipment responds to that by resonating with the air.

I personally cannot stand this effect and will toss an adapter making this hissing and chirping type noises since besides the noise factor it could indicate a fully loaded inductor coil or a cheaply made one. Either way with no tolerance for an extra-long charge session on a warm summer day they aren't worth the risk. -IMHO

Comment: The hum can be useful though.  I've got one wall wart that hums at ~15kHz when it isn't loaded.  Quite handy to tell when my phone's done charging!

Answer (score 2):

You may also be hearing the power supply enter "skip mode", where the load is too light to justify switching on the power silicon for every cycle. The frequency that it enters and leaves skip mode may be responsible for the audible noise, or perhaps an intermodulation of the two.

[image: skip mode waveforms, from paper below]

Here is a whitepaper from TI about one of their specific regulators and how/why it skips along:

https://e2echina.ti.com/cfs-filesystemfile/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-00-01-79-75/Understanding-TPS61175-_1920_-s-Pulse_2D00_Skipping-Function.pdf